# Using a barcode scanner in Excel to find a cell and decrease value by 1?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to make my inventory count more efficient and don't even know if this is possible. I have 10 products with different amounts of quantity that ship out daily. Is there way to give each product a barcode that I can scan in Excel and will automatically find the QTY for that product and decrease the value by 1?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but without knowing more about your use case, we can't tell you how. I mean it could more efficient to buy a $100 cash register that has functions to track sales by product, than your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Alex, youtube is your friend!

On my first search, this came up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yssnGacoTNA (I am not affiliated nor can I vouch for the content or quality of the scanner device).

Here the USB barcode scanner simply acts as a keyboard (wedge or HID mode), sending the barcode numbers through to excel as if you were just typing it in manually on a keyboard. Some basic excel formulae or a few macros / VBA code lines and your inventory system is done.

Without macros / VBA code, you would scan items into a checkout sheet (similar to the video) and simply adjust the totals manually at the end of the day. With VBA you could automate it, perhaps with a little pop up form or input textbox and a confirmation message (to ensure that double scans don't accidentally decrease the total twice).

One possible flaw with this system is that your pc could change focus to another application or to another sheet or column, and you unknowingly scan a barcode into a Word document or email instead of your inventory system. Most barcode scanners should have another means of access (not keyboard mode) but would require more coding. It may be possible to lock the "keyboard mode" to only one application in software.

Also see this mobile phone scanner app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDzAYQ1kbA8